# Behaviour of domains and subdomains for accessing a URL

Tags: web, dns

Why does **analytics.google.com** works while **www.analytics.google.com** does not ??

Comment: Because Google doesn't have a DNS entry for `www.analytics.google.com`, I would imagine.  You can't really just make up names, there has to be a DNS entry for it somewhere to route you to the server.

Comment: @David, I think you should post that as an answer, so it can be accepted. It may  be short for an answer, but there just isn't more to it.

Comment: @Jasper: Eh, Jamie Dixon described it better than I was willing to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David's comment above is accurate. I wanted to expand upon this a little to clarify your thinking of `www.`

`www.` is a subdomain like any other. Whether you use `analytics.` or `www.` or `whateveryouput.`, they're all still just subdomains that are created for the domain in question.

David answers correctly that the reason `www.analytics.` doesn't work is because the subdomain `analytics.` doesn't have a subdomain `www.`.

I think it's important to know that there's nothing particularly special about the `www.` subdomain compared with any other subdomain.